# Can't select a mesh

Tags: outliner

So I am making a character with two articles of "clothing" on him. In object mode I can select the clothing meshes but I can't select him unless I right click him on the outliner and select which is getting really old.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender won't select the object I want to select](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44417/blender-wont-select-the-object-i-want-to-select)

Answer (score 2):

I right clicked and scrolled down to "toggle selectable" and now I can select it.
Derp.