# Adding Textures to Glove Rig

Tags: animation, mesh, texturing, rigging, shaders

So I have made an animation for a pair of gloves, more specifically https://gamebanana.com/models/4308

The problem that I have with this is that I do not know how to apply the textures to the gloves themselves, as whenever I try to select the gloves mesh I always end up selecting the rig, and not the gloves. I had tried hiding the rig but could not select the mesh. I went into the shading tab and there was no option to create a new material for the mesh. If any could help out, that would be appreciated. Also sorry if this post might be a little, "nooby(?)" I've never posted on here before and am still a beginner. Thank you.

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44417/blender-wont-select-the-object-i-want-to-select

Answer (score 1):

The selection of the mesh is disabled, you need to enable it first. It's a 2.79 blend file and for some reason, the materials are not shown correctly in Blender 2.8+. But you can recreate them:

[image: screenshot shading editor]

1. Add the Shading workspace: *[+] → Sculpting → Shading*
2. Click the *Filter* icon, and select the first 5 *Restriction Toggles*. This includes *Selection*, the arrow icon.
3. The mesh is parented to the armature. Expand it and look for *CSGOMotogloves*. Activate *Selection* (arrow icon). Now you can select the mesh. Select it.
4. Materials exist already. Select one to recreate
5. Check *Use Nodes* in the shading editor
6. Add the *Image Texture* nodes and the *Normal Map* node. Select the images for the *Image Texture* nodes. Don't forget to set *Color Space* to *Non-Color* for the normal map image.

Repeat steps 4 to 6 for the remaining 2 materials. That's it :-)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it thank you for responding!